# How I can sort a each number in a given number?

Tags: groovy

I know i can make use of `sort()` function in Groovy to sort List. For example I can do this :

```
def numbers = [1,4,3] as List
print numbers.sort() // outputs : [1,3,4]
```

Now i want to know whether there is a function in Groovy, which does something like this:

```
def number = 143
// any method there to apply on number, so that i can get 134 as output!?
// that is i get sorted my number?
```

Correct me if am wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
def number = 143
def sorted = "$number".collect { it as int }.sort().join() as int
```

That:

1. Converts the number to a String `"$number"`
2. `collect`s each char as an int (so you get a List of int)
3. calls `sort()` on this array
4. calls `join()` to stick all the ints back together as a String
5. then calls `as int` to convert this String back into an int

---

As an aside, you don't need to do:

```
def numbers = [1,4,3] as List
```

in your example code... `[1,4,3]` is a `List` already, so `as List` is superfluous

Comment: @tim, looks good but doesn't work in console -- get a no matching constructor for int() on line: def sorted = "$number".collect { it as int }.sort().join() as int

Comment: Works in my console. The "as int" in the collect closure could be ommited, as the sort also works with String representation of digits.

Comment: @virtual Odd... it works on the web console, and the desktop console for 1.8

Comment: @Christoph ... very true, as they're single digits this would work too :-)

Comment: @tim, yes, strange, I copied pasted too. Now I see why, pasted into console snippet where I was working on overriding String MCL asType(), no wonder. Order is restored, Groovy 1.8 works for everyone, even here on Linux ;-)

Comment: @tim: oh fine, thanks for the answer :) and +1 for the explanation :)

Comment: @tim : what i have to do, if i have to get a descending order?

Comment: @ant `def sorted = "$number".collect { it as int }.sort { -it }.join() as int`

Comment: @tim, +1, that is really cool, so .sort{-it} is the same as .sort().reverse().

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

And this is even better (@tim has the answer so don't change please, just working on my Groovy chops ;-))

a descending order version would be:

```
def n = 143
println "$n".collect{it}.sort().reverse().join().toInteger() // or "as int" as you like
```

**Edit**
This is a bit better:

```
def n = 143 as String
println n.collect{it}.sort().join().toInteger()
```

**Original**
Hacked, but works:

```
def n = 143.collect{it}.join(',').toList().sort().join()
```